# send form data to php using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I know this is a repetitive question, but please help me. I have this code which send form data to php using ajax, but the code doesn't work and I don't know why. Any help please ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function chk(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var datastring = 'name = ' + name;
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"hi.php",
        data: datastring,
        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
            $('msg').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

     <form>
       <input type="text" name="id" >
       <input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="return chk()">

        </form>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$name=$_POST['name'];

echo $name."<br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  When you debug this, where does it fail?  Are there any errors in the browser console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the data in that request?  What is the server's response?

Comment: In your code you use this line right here: `var name = document.getElementById('name').value;`. But where is the element `name` defined? I cannot find this in your form, I see an element with the name id, but no id name...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** your code is looking for an element with `id` of `name` when you use this line: `var name = document.getElementById('name').value;` . However there are no elements with that Id in your HTML. Also, you're triggering the element with id of `msg` but you are not telling it its an ID, since no hash `#` is present.

**Solution:** since you are already using jQuery, I would stick with its functions, specifically `submit()` and `serialize()`. Redo your code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <p id="msg"></p>
        <script>
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "hi.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#msg').html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't do anything:

```
$('msg').html(html);
```

Because there are no `<msg>` tags in your markup.  Perhaps you meant to reference the element with the `id` of `"msg"`?:

```
$('#msg').html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting the html response to: $('msg').html(html);
I think you mean `$('#msg').html(html);` Notice the '#' to reference an element by id.